# after screenRotation the language of application change

Tags: android

I'm working on Android app which contain two languages faced a problem when I rotate the device then  navigate to next page the 
 language of the next page change  I want it to stay at the language which user choose.
 any reason for this problem?

I added at Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

but the problem doesn't solve.

the user choose the language at login screen:
then it save it at lang class:

```
public void changeApplicationLanguage(String langName) {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(getResources()
            .getConfiguration());

    if (langName.equals("en")) {
        configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        Constant.LANGUAGE = 2;
    } else {
        configuration.locale = new Locale("France");
        Constant.LANGUAGE = 1;
    }

    getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: are you using shared Preference or from where the user choose the language , plz post your code

Comment: the language choose at login page...then all the app change

Comment: `Constant.LANGUAGE = 2;` is strange: if it is really a constant you can't assign a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

redefine the language at each activity on nConfigurationChanged.